# LibreOffice Writer crashing on Debian "buster" with Gnome desktop

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, libreoffice

I had the problem with `libreoffice --writer` crashing on my system without any message. `libreoffice --calc` was working without any problem. (I did not check on the others like `draw` or `impress`).

I have been able to just start `libreoffice` without any option, but experienced the same crash when selecting `new writer document` from the GUI.

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid
            Kernel: Linux 4.13.0-1-686-pae
      Architecture: x86
       LibreOffice: 1:5.4.2-3
```

I did not have this problem with the same versions on a 64bit system.

I now worked around this issue by removing the libreoffice gtk3 package.

```
apt remove libreoffice-gtk3
```

I can live with this though it does not look very nice,
but is there any better workaround, that does not involve a downgrade?

Comment: Does it help if you move your configuration out of the way? `mv ~/.config/libreoffice{,.old}`

Comment: @StephenKitt; no, unfortunately not. The only difference it makes is that it shows the `Splash Screen` a second time at a different position before crashing :-) when launching from the terminal. Selecting the document type from the GUI seems to crash the same way as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This seems to be fixed since version:** `1:5.4.3-4+b1`

Libre Office did not run anymore, with or without: `libreoffice-gtk3`
It just quit without any message when started from the terminal, with or without option (`--calc` `--writer`...)

**Happily this time it could be fixed** as @StephenKitt recommended earlier by moving the old configuration files out of the way.

```
mv ~/.config/libreoffice{,.old}
```

since then it also runs with: `libreoffice-gtk3`

**On the first start I got the error message:**

```
$ libreoffice 
error
xsltParseStylesheetFile : cannot parse 
I/O warning : failed to load external entity ""
error
xsltParseStylesheetFile : cannot parse
```

though only on the first start.

Now it seems to run quite stable and lots faster then before.

Answer (score 0):

in my case problem solved with remove this package

```
sudo apt purge mesa-opencl-icd
```